# Classifications of cubic surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-fields

Is there a known classification of singular cubic surfaces over finite fields?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question? What you mean by "classification"? Do you only care about large finite fields or do you really care about small finite fields? Do you e.g. want to know whether every possible ADE singularity for cubic surfaces over $\mathbb{C}$ can occur for some cubic surfaces over $\mathbb{F}_2$? As finite fields are not algebraically closed there are also subtitles regarding whether the singularities are defined over the base field or over a finite field extension and conjugate under the Galois action.

Comment: Hirschfeld, in his book titled "Finite projective spaces of three dimensions" classified all the quadric surfaces in $\mathbb{F}_q$. I am looking for similar results for cubic surfaces. I do care about every finite fields, one could ignore characteristic 2 though. It is fine to consider the singularities even over algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: It might help to recall Hirschfeld's classification to make precise what kind of "classification" you are looking for.

Comment: I do not have a soft copy for Hirschfeld's book, but the following paper (https://ac.els-cdn.com/S1071579706000414/1-s2.0-S1071579706000414-main.pdf?_tid=c6ec9fc0-cf0b-11e7-8e17-00000aacb361&acdnat=1511303695_a56168ec02117082891eb56068753f8f) mentions it in page 621, Table 1.

Comment: So you are interested in a classification up to the action of $\mathrm{PGL}_4(\mathbb{F}_q)$? Do you want specific list of possible equations over each $\mathbb{F}_q$? Or do you just want to know all possible singularity types? The case of quadrics is quite different from the case of cubic surfaces; there are $6$ isomorphism classes of quadric surfaces over each $\mathbb{F}_q$, but the number of isomorphism classes of cubic surfaces over $\mathbb{F}_q$ grows as $q \to \infty$; this is why I'm not sure what you want by classification, as it the number of possibilities is growing.

Comment: Do you have some specific application in mind? This would help more understand what you want.

Comment: For application to problems which I am currently working on, I need to understand the structure of an (absolutely) irreducible cubic surface defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$ containing at least one line $\ell$ defined over $\mathbb{F}_q$. I need to especially understand the singular cubics. How would they look like when we take intersection of the surface with planes passing through the line $\ell$? So I thought understanding the isomorphism classes of cubic surfaces may help me. Could you tell me a reference of the fact that "number of isomorphism classes of cubic surfaces grows with $q$?

Comment: First the proof that "number of isomorphism classes of cubic surfaces grows with $q$" is very easy. A cubic surface has $20$-coefficients, so cubic surfaces form a $19$-projective space. But $\dim \mathrm{PGL}_4 = 15$, so the quotient is $4$-dimensional. An application of the Lang--Weil estimates show that there are roughly $q^4$ isomorphism classes of cubic surfaces as $q \to \infty$. A similar argument shows that there are $q^3$ isomorphism classes of *singular* cubic surfaces, as the singular surfaces form a geometrically irreducible divisor in the $\mathbb{P}^{19}$.

Comment: As for your other question, taking the residual intersection of the planes with a given line gives rise to a conic bundle structure on the surface with $5$ singular fibres over the algebraic closure, at least if your surface is not too singular.

Comment: Maybe the thesis of Nathan Kaplan (https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/11124839/kaplan_gsas.harvard_0084l_10896.pdf?sequence=1) and the paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.00300.pdf) and the references therein might be useful to you. (Kaplan specifically deals with singular surfaces)

Comment: Thanks for your replies. By the conic bundle structure with 5 singular fibres, do you mean something like Proposition 7.3 in Miles Reid's book?

Comment: Yes. But the difference in the case of singular cubic surfaces is that you can also get a "double line" as a fibre (in the smooth case you only get a smooth conic or 2 lines meeting in a point for the residual intersection)

Comment: Where would I find about these conic fibres for singular cubics?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not much in the literature on conic bundles on singular surfaces... Normally one just performs a resolution of singularities to get a smooth surface. For many applications this is sufficient. It all depends on exactly what you ultimately need.

Comment: Feel free to send me an email if you would like to discuss your problem in more depth.

Comment: Alright, I will do so.